# Using Apple ID as login method - Can the App Developer track you, if you delete your account and re-do this?

Tags: applications, apple-id, privacy

Let's say an iOS app lets you use your Apple ID as your login method, and you create an account this way.

I suppose they don't get your APPLE ID, bur rather some scrambled, right?

Then, if you delete the account you just created on the app, and re-create a new account, using the same Apple ID, can the app developer figure that it is you again?

If not, why, is it because the scramble changed each time?

And what if you had a "subscription" when creating the first account, and you "recover" it while using the second account, can the app developer figure it's you in that specific case?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things in play here - I believe you're referring to Sign in with Apple but I've mentioned the other one for completeness.

## Sign in with Apple

SIWA emails cannot be reset, just disabled/re-created. If you delete it from Settings > Apple ID > iCloud > Hide My Email > [Select the Account] > Manage Settings > Stop Using Apple ID the account will clear out and the email will stop working, but it may return in the future.

Since Sign in with Apple doesn't require installing the app, there is no connection between having the app or not having it, to the SIWA association.

## CloudKit Account ID

Developers also have the option of getting an Apple ID account identifier that is unique to that app. You can usually reset this data by finding the app in your iCloud storage tab and deleting the data associated with it.

Comment: Thanks, it's the right direction, but it's not enough information.
About Sign in with Apple, my question is: SIWA creates a `[string]@privaterelay.appleid.com` email, which I can see Under Settings->Apple ID->Security->Apps using Apple ID.
However, if I "Stop using Apple ID", and then Re-create an account via SIWA, I still get the same exact email with the same string. I see no way to alternatve this email. So my privacy is comporomised in the sense that the app developer can link my new account to my old account via email. Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: And about Cloud Kit, I don't see anything under my iCloud storage tab that is related to any app. I go to Apple ID->Icloud, and I See nothing under manage storage that is related to any app.

Comment: When you click Apple ID > iCloud you can choose Manage Storage and you'll see all your apps that store data in iCloud. That being said, Sign in with Apple is more likely the issue you want to focus on in this scenario.

Comment: As to your concerns there, sounds like I was wrong and you can't actually reset this. That being said, this is probably intentional. Part of the SIWA pitch is that it gives developers confidence they're not being spammed since Apple is backing the accounts quality. If you can re-create SIWA with a new ID, that would allow unlimited "non spam" accounts to be created.